# RegionPlot fails

Tags: plotting, syntax, regions

Consider a function

```
f[x_,y_]:=NIntegrate[g[x,y,z],{z,1.1*x,3000}]
```

where g[x,y,z] is some function. The function f[x,y] is smooth and works perfectly when Plot it. However, when using

```
RegionPlot[f[10^x,10^y],{x,-3,62.5},{y,-20,-10}]
```

I got the message

```
Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[-Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x]+(Holonomic`DifferentialRootReduceDump`y^\[Prime])[NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`x],NIntegrate`LevinRuleDump`FastLookupHolonomicDifferentialEquation] returned to top level.
```

I tried to remove it by modifying

```
f[x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[g[x,y,z],{z,1.1*x,3000}]
RegionPlot[f[10^x,10^y],{x,-3,62.5},{y,-20,-10},"NumericalFunction"->False]
```

I got that `1.1*10^x is not a valid limit of integration.`

What is the problem with this RegionPlot?

Comment: Have you done `Clear[f]` before the second definition of `f`? You can check with `?f` whether the first definition (the `f[x_,y_]:=` one) is still lingering around.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot´